# Align items horizontally bootstrap

Tags: reactjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap grid layout in my web app I want to align all on the same line. For example, when loading in full screen, the cards look as follows:

[image]

However, when the page is resized, the cards appear as follows

[image]

I need to make them look like the first image regardless of how the page is resized, jut not sure how to go about doing this.

Below is my code:

```
   <div className="d-flex col-sm-6">
      <div className="" style={{backgroundColor: 'white', borderRadius: 5, border: '1px solid #EAE8E8'}}>
        <div className="row">
          <div className="d-flex col-md-8">
            <div className="row" style={{paddingTop: 20, paddingBottom: 20, paddingLeft: 40}}>
              <h4>
                <b>{this.props.restaurant.name}</b>&nbsp;
                {this.props.restaurant.dietaryRestrictions.map(function(dietaryRestriction, index) {
                  return(<div key={index}><span className="badge-sm badge-secondary" style={{color: 'white', backgroundColor: '#DA9550', fontSize: 9}}>{dietaryRestriction}</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</div>);
                })}
              </h4>
             {this.props.restaurant.description}
              <br /><br />
             <span className="munchtime pointer"><i className="fas fa-check"></i> <b>Add to Cart</b></span><br /><br />
                <b><s>${this.props.restaurant.price}</s></b> <span className="discount"><b>${this.props.restaurant.price * this.props.restaurant.restaurant.discount}</b></span>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className="d-flex col-md-4">
                <img src={this.props.restaurant.images[0]} style={{width: '100%', height: 250, objectFit: 'cover'}} />
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just divide the grid in 5 by 3 manner for all views (xs, sm, md) as container total width is 8.

media queries breakpoints : [grid-media-queries](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/css/#grid-media-queries)

example is below with the

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
     <div class="d-flex col-md-8">
      <div class="" style="background-color: 'white', border-radius: 5, border: '1px solid #EAE8E8'">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="d-flex col-xs-5 col-sm-5 col-md-5">
            <div class="row" style="padding-top: 20, padding-bottom: 20, padding-left: 40">
              <h4>
                <b> restaurant name</b>&nbsp;
                
                  <div key=1><span class="badge-sm badge-secondary" style="color: 'white', background-color: '#DA9550', font-size: 9">dietaryRestriction</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</div>
               
              </h4>
                 restaurant description
              <br /><br />
             <span class="munchtime pointer"><i class="fas fa-check"></i> <b>Add to Cart</b></span><br /><br />
                <b><s>$2000</s></b> <span class="discount"><b>20%</b></span>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="d-flex col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
                <img src='https://picsum.photos/200/300
' style="width: '100%', height: 250, objectFit: 'cover'" />
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code, you are using **col-md-8** which will work from min-width of 992px. you can replace **md** with **xs**, so that it will work for all resolutions.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div className="d-flex col-sm-6">
  <div className="" style={{backgroundColor: 'white', borderRadius: 5, border: '1px solid #EAE8E8'}}>
    <div className="row">
      <div className="d-flex col-xs-8">
        <div className="row" style={{paddingTop: 20, paddingBottom: 20, paddingLeft: 40}}>
          <h4>
            <b>{this.props.restaurant.name}</b>&nbsp;
            {this.props.restaurant.dietaryRestrictions.map(function(dietaryRestriction, index) {
              return(<div key={index}><span className="badge-sm badge-secondary" style={{color: 'white', backgroundColor: '#DA9550', fontSize: 9}}>{dietaryRestriction}</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</div>);
            })}
          </h4>
         {this.props.restaurant.description}
          <br /><br />
         <span className="munchtime pointer"><i className="fas fa-check"></i> <b>Add to Cart</b></span><br /><br />
            <b><s>${this.props.restaurant.price}</s></b> <span className="discount"><b>${this.props.restaurant.price * this.props.restaurant.restaurant.discount}</b></span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="d-flex col-xs-4">
            <img src={this.props.restaurant.images[0]} style={{width: '100%', height: 250, objectFit: 'cover'}} />
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You should only have to adjust the "col" className so that it is always 8 and 4 on any breakpoint.